# How do I access the wp-admin interface of a site that lives inside a joomla folder, using IP address / siteground server URL?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, ip-address, joomla

For historical reasons, we have several sites that live inside the public_html folder of a different site (all hosted on sitegrounds).

To complicate things up, the root domain has a name that is the intended address of the site.

So the root domain is called `123.example.com`
The 456 subdomain (for the 456.example.com site, built in wordpress) has a root.subdomain of `456.123.example.com`

The problem is, the site living in the root is a joomla site with SEO rewrite URL active. So, when I try to access

```
abcd.siteground.xy/~cpanelusername/123.example.com
```

it gets rewrited as

```
123.cpanel.com/en/~cpanelusername/123.example.com
```

which is a 404 joomla page.

Trying to access `abcd.siteground.xy/~cpanelusername/456.example.com` gives a wordpress "page not found" error, which makes me think the path is right...

...but going to `abcd.siteground.xy/~cpanelusername/456.example.com/wp-admin` gets redirected to `123.example.com/en/~cpanelusername/456.example.com/wp-admin` (404 joomla page)

Can I access the wp admin interface without disabling joomla's SEO URL rewrite?

Comment: Fix the issue... don't band-aid it. Update your Joomla config & SQL database replacing old paths with new ones.